# Cannot install 2 Android apps on my device: the one is copy of the other but use different database

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I want to install two Android apps on my device: The one is copied project of the other but will write to different sqlite database (different app name, icon, and database).

First, I created the app "ItalianWords", I installed it on my device (HTC Desire X) and filled it in with words.

Next, I copied the project of the above app in Eclipse, I renamed it to "RussianWords", I changed the package name and I also renamed the application name to "RussianWords" (in AndroidManifest.xml   and strings.xml), I confirmed the changes to .project, I changed the launcher app icon and finally I changed the DataBase name and the FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE name in the Java file, in order to be sure not overriding to my "ItalianWords" app database.

I then installed the "RussianWords" app to my device and I surprisingly saw the "RussianWords" app icon to have replace the "ItalianWords" app icon. The "ItalianWords" app had been disappead from my installed apps. The database of this newly installed app had no data.

I re-installed the "ItalianWords" app, and the same story again: The "RussianWords" app icon had been replaced by the "ItalianWords" app icon, the "RussianWords" app had been disappeared from my device's installed apps but fortunately the "ItalianWords" app database was full of data!

Do you have any idea what should I do?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you change the package name from the gradle or only in java package / manifest?

Comment: Only in java package/ manifest. I 'm still using Eclipse, I have not migrated to Android Studio yet.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your case, having RussianWords app:

- Create a new project called ItalianWords with different package of RussianWords
- Copy all the needed libraries and needed changes to the italian gradle
- Copy all the classes that you need from RussianWords (java, xml and manifest) and paste them on ItalianWords
- Command + shift + r, and replace all the old packages names for the new package names. Example, com.kkats.russianwords to com.kkats.italianwords
- Change everything to italianWords in the manifest.

That worked for me